# Node and Instance Relationship on Oracle RAC

Tags: oracle, instance

I'd like to ask about the process of Node and Instance on Oracle RAC functionality.
I know that RAC provides Failover, a RAC feature that keeps an application running even if the node that was servicing its request failed to operate.
Well so if RAC enters the Failover mode, is that mean the instance that was on the failure node will be shutted down or it was transferred to another node?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

In general, it would mean that the instance that was servicing the request failed and is no longer running.  In a RAC cluster, you run one instance on each node of the cluster.  I wouldn't make sense to move an instance from one node to another in the cluster-- that would imply that one node would be running two instances of the same database.  Depending on your environment, the DBA might choose to add a new node (and a new instance) to the RAC cluster at least temporarily in response to the failure of one of the instances.